# Why can't I consume my webservice more than once?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

When I consuming a webservice (asmx) the first time and return a `DataTable` to my aspx project, everything is ok. However, if I consume the webservice again on that same aspx the previous `DataTable` object is completely empty. Why is that?

This is my webservice method:

```
<WebMethod()> _
public Function QueryGeneralText() As DataTable

    ds.Reset()
    com.Parameters.Clear()
    com.CommandText = queryString
    com.CommandType = select booksID from Books"
    com.Connection = con

    conectarBD()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(com)
    da.Fill(ds)
    con.Close()

    Return ds.Tables(0)
End Function
```

---

On the aspx.vb section:

```
Public Sub CreateDatatable()
  Dim example1 As DataTable = ws.QueryGeneralText() ' RETURNS DATA
  Dim example2 As DataTable = ws.QueryGeneralText() ' RETURNS DATA, BUT EXAMPLE ITS EMPTY
End Sub
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error in the first code block posted (notice the highlight colors are messed up).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a global ds object - so you function is working on the same resultset.

First time you execute the function it works, nobody else has any results in ds, but next time you already have results there but now your reset drops the results.

If this is true, you might fix it by creating the ds inside the function instead if possible.

Comment: thanks very much, it makes sense every single query belongs to that dataset unless you always create a new one which is the best